# .NET Core options missing in target framework dropdown after upgrading to Visual Studio 15.9.6

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I had VS2017 15.9.1 installed, as well as the .NET Core 2.0 SDK.

In my target framework for my project, .NET Core 2.0 was selected. 
I then installed the .NET 2.2 SDK and runtime, but it never showed up in the target framework dropdown in project settings, only .NET 2.0 still appeared.

I then upgraded to VS 15.9.6, restarted my PC, and when I opened my solution, all .NET Core items were removed from the target framework dropdown, only regular .NET Framework options became available.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try executing dotnet --version in the package manager console and if you get an error you should probably reinstall/repair the .NET Core SDK...

Comment: Nope, runs fine, returns 2.2.103

Comment: "I then upgraded to VS 15.9.6, restarted my PC, and when I opened my solution, all .NET Core items were removed from the target framework dropdown, only regular .NET Framework options became available." That means your project file was not valid for .NET Core, and you probably should create a new .NET Core project instead.

Comment: How can it not be 'valid' for .NET core? This project was running fine using .NET Core 2.0 for weeks.